# Start flip switch handle in middle on page load

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

Is it anyway possible to start the flip toggle switch handle in the middle of the slider to initially show the two slider options so that the user can know what the two options are right away instead of toggling the switch?

Comment: No, the jquery mobile flipswitch widget has 2 states, on and off.  It doesn't support the indeterminate state of a checkbox

Comment: i put together an example of a 3 state swith for jQuery Mobile answering another question: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/m48dT/116/ might be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot ezanker, that looks a lot like what I'm looking for.